# how do you convert pandas data frame epoch values to readable datetime format

Tags: python, epoch

I have a data frame like this:

```
print(df)
Metric  TimeStamp       Value
cpu     1642039200000   4
cpu     1642042800000   3
cpu     1642046400000   5
```

I need to convert TimeStamp to readaable time stamp yearmonthdate hour:min:sec

I have tried:

import datetime

```
df['TimeStamp']=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df['TimeStamp'])
```

does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` expects a single value. To work with series, use pandas' methods:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp']*1000000, utc=True).dt.tz_convert('EST').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ts': [1642039200000, 1642042800000, 1642046400000]}) 
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']*1000000, utc=True).dt.tz_convert('EST')
df['ts']
```

Output:

```
0   2022-01-12 21:00:00-05:00
1   2022-01-12 22:00:00-05:00
2   2022-01-12 23:00:00-05:00
Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns, EST]
```

To get a specific string format, `df['ts'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` will output:

```
0    2022-01-12
1    2022-01-12
2    2022-01-12
Name: ts, dtype: object
```

Comment: TimeStamp is already in epoch format. I need this to be EST time

Comment: the timestamp values are already in epoch format. Do I still need to multiply that 1m? I tried this but the values in data frame is not changing to readable. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @user1471980 updated with an example